# pandas series/df.replace - can no longer replace substring when passing dict (version issue? .24.1)

Tags: python, pandas

____###update: downgrading to .23.4 produced the expected results - .24 and .24.1 produced the below. Has anyone else seen this? Any suggestions on updating the syntax below to achieve desired result? Thanks!

---

code for series.replace is no longer working the same as prior pandas versions and i'm having trouble locating the change in the docs and/or adjusting my code to accommodate (i recently upgraded to .24.1)

i usually pass a dictionary to search and replace substrings in a df given column (or series) via s.replace: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html

In the past, pandas would replace substrings that appeared in the middle/end of strings, but now it only seems to work if the pattern is at the very beginning.

I saw the docs mention that passing a dict and using regex follows re.sub, but when I tried that, I got the desired result (not the one pandas yielded). Would appreciate a) any references on what changed and/or b) help adjusting the code so it works similar to re.sub example below - thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import re   

s = pd.Series(['hello there', 'well hello then'])
print(s)

'''OUTPUT
0        hello there
1    well hello then
dtype: object
'''

s.replace({'hello' : 'goodbye'}, regex=True, inplace=True)

print(s)

'''OUTPUT
0      goodbye there
1    well hello then  #<-not replaced
dtype: object
'''

x = re.sub('hello','goodbye', 'hello there')
print(x) 
#out: goodbye there

x = re.sub('hello','goodbye', 'well hello then')
print(x)
#out: well goodbye then    #<-expected result
```

Comment: Can not reproduced

Comment: thanks @Wen-Ben, i'm on pandas .24.1/python 3.7 - are you on .24.1? i've been checking other libraries to see if those are out of date, but not sure which ones (or if it even is a library issue)

Comment: Appears to be a bug, when 'hello' is at the start it does replace but not inside string. See [demo](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/75cac86f-5e13-4bbd-9284-08a70e2de7cc/?i=true) (be sure to click run). [Open an issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) on the Pandas Git page. But `Series.str.replace` work fine.